# optimal separation of vector on pairs of its elements

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

I am looking for suitable algorithm to solve the following problem:

For vector v (Nx1, double, single) I need to find assigments of items of this vector (pairs) that fulfil following conditions:

1. Each item is in assigned in only one pair
2. sum of item distances over all assigned pairs (violation) is minimal
3. as an input of the function is additional parameter vio_max which limits violation of non assignment

[pairs,dist, vio] = findpairs(v,vio_max)

ExampleA:

Input: v = [3.0 2.1 0.9 2.9  1.1 ] , vio_max = 1.0

Output: pairs = [1 4; 3 5], dist = [0.1; 0.2], vio = sum(dist) = 0.3

and item 2.1 remains unassigned (for lenght(v) is odd)

ExampleB:

Input: v = [3.0 2.1 0.9 2.9  1.1 ] , vio_max = 0.15

Output: pairs = [1 4], dist = [0.1], vio = sum(dist) = 0.1

**Note:**
Problem is completely solved, see: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106214/find-separate-pairs-of-points-with-minimal-total-distance

Comment: I assume that you also want to somehow favor more pairs being generated, otherwise the answer in both examples would be `pairs = [1 4]` (ignoring the trivial `pairs = []`). Given a choice between 3 pairs with cost `a` and 2 pairs with cost `b`, how do you choose between the two options?

Comment: The linked solution is fine. You've neglected to include `vio_max`, but that just breaks the problem down into subsets.